# jQuery $Ajax Post data from webform to code behind method in ASP.NET

Tags: webforms, asp.net-3.5, jquery-ajaxq

I am trying to pass data from webform to code behind method and get back value in webform, followed by print it. I have initially test following code to simply post request to method, get string and print in page and it worked, but got issue when trying to post data back to method

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".AddStaffToRoleLink").on("click", function () {

           var selectedStaffID = $(this).attr("id");

           alert("this is " + selectedStaffID);

           $.ajax({

               type: "POST",
               url: "AddUserInRole.aspx/AddRoleForSelectStaff",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               data: { selectedStaffID: selectedStaffID },
               success: function (response) {
                   $("#Content").text(response.d);
               },
               failure: function (response) {
                   alert(response.d);
               }
           });
       });

});
```

### Code behind

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static string AddRoleForSelectStaff(string selectedStaffID)
    {
        return "This string is from Code behind  " + selectedStaffID;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

here is way to post sigle data to webform code behind method...

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

 $(".AddStaffToRoleLink").on("click", function () {

           var selectedStaffID = $(this).attr("id");

           alert("this is " + selectedStaffID);

           $.ajax({
               url: 'AddUserInRole.aspx/AddRoleForSelectStaff',
               type: "POST",
               data: "{'GivenStaffID':'" + selectedStaffID +"'}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (response) {
                   $("#Content").text(response.d);
               },
               failure: function (response) {
                   alert(response.d);
               }
           }).done(function (response) {
               alert("done "+response );
           });
       });
   });
```

### Code Behind method

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string AddRoleForSelectStaff(string GivenStaffID)
    {
        var staffID = Convert.ToInt32(GivenStaffID);

        return "This string is from Code behind  " + GivenStaffID;
    }
```

Comment: looks like it must be a STATIC method.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        string jsonString = "";
        using (StreamReader inputStream = new     StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream))
        {
            jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        JSONRequest masterDetails =   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONRequest>(jsonString);
 }

public class JSONRequest
{
    public long Org { get; set; }
    public long Dept { get; set; }
    public long Desg{ get; set; }
    public long Grp { get; set; }
    public long SubGrp { get; set; }
    public long Loc { get; set; }
    public long Cat { get; set; }
    public string Prv { get; set; }
    public long CustAttrId { get; set; }
    public string CustAttrVal { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

function GetEmployee()
{
    var jsonObj = {"Org":0,"Dept":0,"Desg":0,"Grp":0,"SubGrp":0,"Loc":0,"Prv":'CanViewEmployee',"CustAttrI    d":0,CustAttrVal:"","Status":'1' };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'EmployeeSearchControl.aspx/populateJsonResult',
        datatype: 'json',
        data:JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
        method: 'Post',
        success: function (data) {
            if(data != null || data != "")
            {
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                {
                    addEmployeeToGrid(data[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function GetEmployee()
    {
        var jsonObj = {"Org":0 ,"Dept":0,"Desg":0,"Grp":0,"SubGrp":0,"Loc":0,"Prv":'CanViewEmployee',"CustAttrId":0,CustAttrVal:"","Status":'1' };
        $.ajax({
            url: 'EmployeeSearchControl.aspx/populateJsonResult',
            datatype: 'json',
            data:JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
            method: 'Post',
            success: function (data) {
                if(data != null || data != "")
                {
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                    {
                        addEmployeeToGrid(data[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }


 public class JSONRequest
    {
        public long Org { get; set; }
        public long Dept { get; set; }
        public long Desg{ get; set; }
        public long Grp { get; set; }
        public long SubGrp { get; set; }
        public long Loc { get; set; }
        public long Cat { get; set; }
        public string Prv { get; set; }
        public long CustAttrId { get; set; }
        public string CustAttrVal { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            string ap = Request["org"];
            HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            string jsonString = "";
            using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
            JSONRequest masterDetails = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONRequest>(jsonString);
}
```